# SBC with RS-232 (>= 2) and a case

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded-systems, sbc

I am looking for a single-board-computer with the following requirements.

- performance is not too important
- must support modern Linux (Debian)
- 2 (better 3) RS-232 interfaces
- availability of a compact case with RS-232 9-pin holes

I would find many embedded PCs from industrial hardware manufactors with casing but the lifetime of that is only a few years. Afterwards they only have new boards and new cases.

I would love to use a RasperryPI. It is longtime available and cheap.
But the problem is the RS-232 in conjunction with the case.

Comment: Are USB -> serial adapters and using the GPIO header absolutely out of the question?

Comment: USB is ok as long it is INSIDE the case.

Comment: Would you be comfortable fabricating your own case? Between the header and USB ports, should be able to get plenty of serial connections. Unfortunately most SBCs don't come with cases, so we'd probably be back to looking at embedded PCs. Unfortunately since you're in a difficult environment, finding a case that's available with the specs you need that's durable enough to withstand years of beating probably won't happen. From personal experience, making one really isn't too bad though.

Comment: [Also did find this nice serial HAT.](https://www.pishop.us/product/serial-hat-rs232/)